# get clientId immediately after Service Worker registration

Tags: service, registration, worker, clientid

I would like to Uniquely identify each window or tab controlled by the Service Worker,
I've read about **clienId** and the only way I figured I can achieve its value is by FetchEvent:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/clientId

As far as i think about it, each client should have clientId assigned on registration, so I'm sure there must be a way to get it immediately after registration "then" function and just didn't figure out how,
thanks for helping :)

Comment: Have you found a way to determine clientID before a Fetch event?

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1557